# convert switch statement to one if only in PHP

Tags: php, php-7

I am trying to print numbers from 1 to 50. for multiple of 3 it should print "multiple of 3". for multiple of 5 it should print "multiple of 5". for multiple of 3 and 5 it should print "multiple of 3 and 5 both" for other numbers it should print that number.

I tried this below code using switch, it is working. but i can't use switch, ternary  operator or else statement.

Below is my code -

```
function findMultiples($n)  
{  
    $three = 3; // To keep track of multiples of 3  
    $five = 5; // To keep track of multiples of 5

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)  
    {  
        switch ($i) {
        case $i%$three==0 and $i%$five==0:
            echo "multiple of 3 and 5 both";
            break;
        case $i%$three==0:
            echo "multiple of 3";
            break;
        case $i%$five==0:
            echo "multiple of 5";
            break;
        default:
            echo $i;
        }

        echo "<br/>";
    }  

}  

// Driver Code 
findMultiples(50);  //I am getting expected result.
```

how can i get this result by using below if condition on place of switch

```
$printNumbers = "";

if (($i%$three==0 and $i%$five==0) or ($i%$three==0) or ($i%$five==0))    
{  
    $printNumbers = $i;
}  

echo $printNumbers;
```

Comment: If you can’t use an else statement, but only write this as a couple of independent `if` statements one after the other - then you will have to add additional checks. You will have to write a condition for where it is a multiple of 3, but not of 5, and vice versa, explicitly. And for the default case, explicitly test that it is neither.

Comment: @misorude I have to use only one if.  (no else, no ternary)

Comment: Well then do it the way I just explained. (And if you have trouble with that, then properly explain how exactly.)

Comment: I am trying to make it using data structure. @mitkosoft

Comment: You’re not making much sense here. You have four distinct cases to handle - how should that work, with just _one_ if? _“I am trying to make it using data structure”_ - no idea what you mean by that. Do you want a somehow different result, than that what the code you have shown produces?

Comment: @codegeek, so can you use more than one if (no else, no ternary) at the end?

Comment: @mitkosoft, no we have to use only one if condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit weird question, but if you need only ONE `IF` then you can use both comparison and assignment into in order to achieve it:

```
<?php
    function findMultiples($n) {
        $three = 3; // To keep track of multiples of 3
        $five = 5; // To keep track of multiples of 5

        for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++) {
            if (($i % $three == 0 and $i % $five == 0 and $text = 'both 3 and 5') or ($i % $three == 0 and $text = '3') or ($i % $five == 0 and $text = '5') or ($text = 'none')) {
                echo $i.' is divided by '.$text;
            }
            echo '<br>';
        }
    }

    findMultiples(50);
```

Output:

```
1 is divided by none
2 is divided by none
3 is divided by 3
4 is divided by none
5 is divided by 5
6 is divided by 3
7 is divided by none
8 is divided by none
9 is divided by 3
10 is divided by 5
11 is divided by none
12 is divided by 3
13 is divided by none
14 is divided by none
15 is divided by both 3 and 5
16 is divided by none
17 is divided by none
18 is divided by 3
19 is divided by none
20 is divided by 5
21 is divided by 3
22 is divided by none
23 is divided by none
24 is divided by 3
25 is divided by 5
26 is divided by none
27 is divided by 3
28 is divided by none
29 is divided by none
30 is divided by both 3 and 5
31 is divided by none
32 is divided by none
33 is divided by 3
34 is divided by none
35 is divided by 5
36 is divided by 3
37 is divided by none
38 is divided by none
39 is divided by 3
40 is divided by 5
41 is divided by none
42 is divided by 3
43 is divided by none
44 is divided by none
45 is divided by both 3 and 5
46 is divided by none
47 is divided by none
48 is divided by 3
49 is divided by none
50 is divided by 5
```

Feel free to change the printed text if needed.

Comment: perfect. i also thought for same but last or statement was needed actually.

Comment: Unusual questions born unusual solutions :)